# Class definition in javascript, keyword "this" not references the class

Tags: javascript, this

I'm not very familiar with javascript's grammar, but I want to define a class, but the keyword this not behave as I want. And I want to know the reason, thanks! The javascript code is below:

```
var GameUI = function(){
        this.ctx = this.ctx || null;
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.chessToMove = {x : -1, y :-1};
        this.style = 'stype_1';
        //this.drawBeginX = 4;
        //this.drawBeginY = 17;
        this.boardStyle = {
            stype_1 : {
                beginX : 4,
                beginY : 17,
                intervalX : 35,
                intervalY : 36,
            },
            stype_2 : {
                beginX : 4,
                beginY : 17,
                intervalX : 10,
                intervalY : 10,
            },
        };

        this.init = function(){
            if(this.canvas && this.canvas.getContext('2d')){
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

                this.loadImgs();
                //set listeners
                this.canvas.addEventListener('click', this.canvasClick, false);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };

        this.setStyle= function(style){
            this.style = style;
        };

        this.canvasClick = function(e){
            //

            let x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft, y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
            //alert('Canvas is clicked! X: '  + x + ",Y: " + y);

            //why this is a canvas obj not a GameUI obj
            console.log(/*'in canvasClick: ' + */this);
        };
    };
```

Html code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title> js test </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .main{
      margin:0 auto;
      width: 80%;
    }
    #canvas{
      border:1px solid black;
    }

 </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class='main'>
<canvas id='canvas' width='800' height='600'> Your browser is not supported for canvas element </canvas>
</div>
<button> new game </button>
</body>

</html>
```

As you see, I defined a GameUI class which a canvas was in it with a click function named canvasClick.But surprisely, in the click function, keyword `this` is a canvas object not a GameUI object, I test it by a log.And this confused me!

Comment: Look up `this` behavior in JS. It doesn't act the same as it does in every other language. Long story short, `this` depends on what object the function was called on, which can change.

Comment: There are no classes in JS, you've a constructor function.

Comment: store the reference of `this` like `var GameUI = function(){ var self = this; ...` and use `self` later

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers **run in the context of the triggering element**, unless told to act otherwise.

This can be changed via `bind`, which tells it to run in some other context.

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('click', this.canvasClick.bind(this), false);
```

Now, in your click callback, `this` will point to the class instance.